# How to write XSD for given XML snippet.?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am pretty new in writing xsd. I'm trying to write for given xml snippet. However I get confuse for location element. There are two location elements. Can someone help me in understanding me if given xml snippet is correct or not. If it is correct how we can define xsd for such scenario.

```
<data>
   <location>
      <name>London</name>
      <type />
      <location altitude="0" latitude="51.5085" longitude="-0.1258" />
   </location>
   <credit />
   ...
```

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  Then [edit] your question and add your XSD attempt to show that you've actually tried to solve your problem yourself before asking for help.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the XML. But to write a schema you have to know what other documents are allowed besides this one. For example, does the `type` element have to be empty, or can it have content, and if so what?

Answer (score 0):

The two locations aren't an issue for creating a XSD.  The below XSD would validate your payload if it was terminated with `</data>`

However as other have said, without knowing the type of both the type & credit element, and also if any of the elements are optional or repeated multiple times, it may not match what you require.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="location">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="location">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="altitude" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="latitude" type="xs:decimal" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="longitude" type="xs:decimal" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="credit" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```